# how to get json array from xml response in swift

Tags: swift

im new to ios. I'm making simple login app using soap request.
so the problem is when I get a response from the server it looks like

```
Optional(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateLoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <CreateLoginResult>[{"DelBoyId":36,"DelBoy_Fname":"abc-xyz","Password":"123","DelBoy_Email":"abc@gmail.com","DelBoy_Contact":"123","RoleName":"Admin"}]
            </CreateLoginResult>
        </CreateLoginResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>).
```

and I want to store this key value `[{"DelBoyId":36,"DelBoy_Fname":"abc-xyz","Password":"123","DelBoy_Email":"abc@gmail.com","DelBoy_Contact":"123","RoleName":"Admin"}]` in session.

how can I do this ? please help me.

thank you.

here is my code

```
import UIKit

class LoginPageViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var txtUserEmail: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var txtUserPassword: UITextField!

    var webData : NSMutableData?
    var parser : NSXMLParser?
    var flag : Bool?
    var capturedString : String?

    func processTerrorSaftyTips(data : NSData){
        parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
        parser!.delegate = self
        parser!.parse()

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let mobile = txtUserEmail.text;
        let password = txtUserPassword.text;


        let soapMessage = String(format: "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http:/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><CreateLogin xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><mobile>"+mobile!+"</mobile><pasword>"+password!+"</pasword></CreateLogin></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://23.91.115.57/nagifts/NaGiftsWebService.asmx");

        let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest (URL: url!);
        let soapLength = String(soapMessage.characters.count)

        theRequest.addValue("text/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
        theRequest.addValue(soapLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST";
        theRequest.HTTPBody = soapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,allowLossyConversion: false);

        let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest , delegate: self);

    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError){

    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse){

        webData = NSMutableData()
    }
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData){

        webData!.appendData(data)
    }
    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection){

        processTerrorSaftyTips(webData!)
    }

    func parserDidStartDocument(parser: NSXMLParser){

        flag = false
        capturedString = ""
    }
    func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser){

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]){

        flag = false
        capturedString = ""
        if elementName == "CreateLoginResult"
        {
            flag = true
        }

    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?){

        flag = false
        if elementName == "CreateLoginResult"
        {
            print((capturedString!))


        }
    }
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String){

        if flag! {
            capturedString = capturedString! + string
        }

    }
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError){

        }

}
```

Comment: you are not using xcode8?

Comment: no.currently I'm using  Xcode7.3  @sanju

Answer (score 1):

Swift3:

Declare any array because your response is in array

```
var arrayFromResult = NSMutableArray()
```

Next go to Parse DidEndElement and add foundCharacters to Array do like this

```
 if elementName == "CreateLoginResult"
  {
        print((capturedString!))
    arrayFromResult.add(capturedString)

   }
```

Usage Of array Or retrieve Dictionary Values from Array

```
  for var i  in 0..<arrayFromResult.count {

        let dictFromArray = arrayFromResult.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary

        let name = dictFromArray.value(forKey: "DelBoy_Fname") as! String
        print(name)

        let password = dictFromArray.value(forKey: "Password") as! String
        print(password)


    }
```

Comment: when i add arrayFromResult.add(capturedString)

Comment: when i add arrayFromResult.add(capturedString) .error occures "value of type  NSMutableArray has nomember add" @Sanju ju

Comment: try writing like this : arrayFromResult.add(capturedString as! NSMutableArray)

Comment: I think response need to change. ask the server people  to change like <Parent><Child></Child><Child></Child>..........</Parent>

Comment: Hey in Xcode 7.3 you need to write like this man  arrayFromResult.addObject(capturedString)

Comment: I think it's not possible to change that.we required JSON array in each request.

Comment: ok. now error comes here** "let dictFromArray = arrayFromResult.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary" **  i changed it to  **"let dictFromArray = arrayFromResult.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary"**

Comment: ok. now error comes here** "let dictFromArray = arrayFromResult.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary" **  i changed it to  **"let dictFromArray = arrayFromResult.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary"** and  also **llet name = dictFromArray.valueForKey("DelBoy_Fname") as! String** there is no error when i build.but when run it shows me **Could not cast value of type __NSCFString to 'NSDictionary'** what i did wrong?

Comment: i wrote in swift3. Just see values in arrayFromResult & dictFromArray print them

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get it.

Comment: print the values arrayFromResult & dictFromArray

Comment: dictFromArray contains  "dictFromArray NSString "[{\"DelBoyId\":36,\"DelBoy_Fname\":\"pranay-Kadam\",\"Password\":\"123\",\"DelBoy_Email\":\"pranay@kssoftech.com\",\"DelBoy_Contact\":\"123\",\"RoleName\":\"Admin\"}]""
but a console  shows   "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7d002fc0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DelBoy_Fname."